# Is it possible to programmatically know which equalizer setting is set on the iphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, settings

Is it possible to programmatically know which equalizer setting is set on the iphone? For example, I can get a list of all presets:

```
UInt32 sizeof1 = sizeof(mEQPresetsArray);
AudioUnitGetProperty(mEQ, kAudioUnitProperty_FactoryPresets,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Global, 0, &mEQPresetsArray, &sizeof1);

UInt8 count = CFArrayGetCount(mEQPresetsArray);
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    AUPreset *aPreset = (AUPreset*)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(mEQPresetsArray, i);
    CFShow(aPreset->presetName);
}
```

But how do you know which preset is selected in the settings?

[image: iOS EQ setting]